# Bash script to pass password with spaces to mysqlshow

Tags: mysql, bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to automate some MySQL backups and I'm using mysqlshow to test whether I've got a successful connection. Its working, but the problem is that some of my MySQL passwords contain spaces and the scripts are choking on passwords that contain spaces.

If I define a variable

```
mysqlshow="mysqlshow -u $user -p'$password' database_name"
```

Then try run that command with

```
result=$($mysqlshow)
```

I get an error from mysqlshow saying `Too many arguments`. This is being caused by spaces in `$password` as it works for passwords without spaces.

Comment: Define `mysqlshow=(mysqlshow -u "$user" -p"'"$password"'" database_name)` and do `result="${mysqlshow[@]}"`

Comment: And quote the variable `result`, when printing, `echo "$result"`

Comment: See: [Why does shell ignore quoting characters in arguments passed to it through variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136948/why-does-shell-ignore-quoting-characters-in-arguments-passed-to-it-through-varia)